# My function as a children is not rendering value from parent component

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-props

How come this happens ?
I want to update the child component when the state of my parent component changes. But nothing is happening as expected. Can someone please help.

- in the Fetch, I encapsulate the networking logic : fetch
- I passed a function as a props with value of data, errors if any and loading state
- in the callback function I render the data to update my UI

below is one demo with a function as a children following the same pattern of render props.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./App.css";

const Fetch = ({ url, children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    loading: false,
    data: null,
    errors: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({ ...state, loading: true });
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setState({ ...state, data: data, loading: false }))
      .catch((err) => setState({ ...state, error: err, loading: false }));
  }, [url]);

  const response = useMemo(() => {
    return state;
  }, [state]);

  if (state.loading) return <div>loading ...</div>;
  if (state.errors) return <div>Something went wrong ...</div>;
  if (!state.data) return <div>Sorry, no results</div>;
  return <div>{children({ response })}</div>;
};

Fetch.propTypes = {
  url: PropTypes.string,
};

function List({ Search }) {
  debugger;
  return Search?.map((item) => <Item {...item} />);
}
function Item({ Title }) {
  return <li className="list-group-item">{Title}</li>;
}
function App() {
  return (
    <Fetch url="http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=deadpool&apikey=158fe49">
      {({ data }) => {
        return (
          <div className="list d-flex justify-content-center">
            <ul className="list-group">
              <List {...data} />
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Fetch>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: debugger - the data is present following the get call]
[image: debugger - data present in the value passed as argument of the children function]
[image: debugger - child component not updating with data from parent component]

Does anyone know why and how to resolve this ?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you might change to `children({ ...response })` or even `children(response)`, because otherwise the children function gets a response prop instead of the contents of it. Let me know if that makes any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `Fetch` component. You probably meant `return <div>{children(response)}</div>`, because `return <div>{children({ response })}</div>` will call the render function with an object that has a key `response`.

Additionally, when this is fixed, the `List` component throws an error because `Search?.map((item) => <Item {...item} />)` will return `undefined` if `Search` is falsy, which is not acceptable. Instead, you should return `null` or `false`.

```
function List({ Search }) {
  return Search ? Search.map((item) => <Item {...item} />) : null;
}
```